# Problem with fonts in Mapnik

Tags: mapnik, font

I am using version 3.0.12 , I have made an XML file and I am using Arial Black and Arial Bold fonts but mapnik was not rendering those fonts. So , I changed the fonts to DejaVu Sans Book and then all my labels are showing up .
Why is it so, since Arial Black and Arial Bold are very common fonts?

Answer (score 1):

According to **[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial)**, Arial fonts are a proprietary typeface.  It's likely that Mapnik doesn't have the license to package Arial fonts with the software.

Mapnik ships with the DejaVu fonts instead. You can add other fonts.  See **[this page](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/UsingCustomFonts)**.